# How to get the current company in xml. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I added a field (type char) in model 'account.payment.register',

```
 <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_register_form"/>  
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='communication']" position="after">
        <field name="company" attrs="{'invisible': [('journal_type', '=', 'cash')], 'required': [('journal_type', '=', 'bank')]}"/>
     </xpath>
   </field>
 </field>
```

I want to add default value in field 'Company' according to these conditions:

- if it is an 'outbound' payment , then Company must get the current company .
- if it is an 'inbound' payment , Company get an empty field.
  Can I do it with xml code ? Any help please ?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **onchange api** and compute company field. If you are using default **company_id** field then you have to remove attribute **related**.

```
@api.onchange('payment_type')
def default_get_company(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.payment_type == 'outbound':
            record.company = self.env.company.id 
            # if its char field then self.env.company.name
        else:
            record.company = ''
```

Comment: can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066061/what-is-the-file-path-of-account-aged-payable-model-and-how-to-edit-aged-payable

Answer (score 0):

```
company = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company', default=lambda self: self.env.company_id.id if self.payment_id == 'outbound' else None)
```

Just add *default* attribute in the ***company*** variable.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can use Mentioned below

[('company_id','=',user.company_id.id)

Comment: I want to set this value only for 'payment_type': 'outbound',